# Delay modal from loading for 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

I am trying to delay the modal from loading for 5 seconds. My code is below

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#overlay').modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {

}, 50000);
});//]]>  

</script>
```

At the moment the modal is loading when the page is loaded. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3):

Look at your code.  You do this right away:

```
$('#overlay').modal('show');
```

Then you set a delay to perform... an empty function:

```
setTimeout(function() {

}, 50000);
```

So after 50 seconds (you have an extra zero), your code will execute that empty function.  Which does nothing.  Instead of doing nothing, you can move your code which does something into that function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('show');
}, 5000);
```

That way (after fixing the extra zero), rather than do something right away the code will wait for 5 seconds and then do something.

Comment: is it possible to set a time even if the user changes page. so after 30 seconds it would load even if the page has changed?

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: When the page is abandoned and a new page is loaded, an entirely new context of JavaScript is running.  Code from the previous page is no longer loaded, so no longer runs.  The new page would have to run a new timer.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: You'll need to persist the current state of the timer somewhere, either in server-side storage (a database, for example) or client-side storage (assuming HTML5, or possibly in a cookie written/read by JavaScript).  In that case a simple `setTimeout` isn't the way to go.  Instead, store something like the target timestamp and then use `setInterval()` to poll the current time periodically (every second, maybe?) and compare it with the target time.  When the current time surpasses the target time, run the code you need to run.